# Constraint layout change constraint programmatically

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a textview:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewChat"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"

    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:text="I have one listView "
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:textColor="@color/bb_darkBackgroundColor"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewChat"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"/>
```

What I want is to delete the last line programmatically because some times I don't need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that you want to change `app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"` to `app:layout_constraintWidth_default="spread"` which is the default.

The following code shows how you can use [`ConstraintSet`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.html) to do this. The XML is just what you have presented but the `ConstraintLayout` has been given the id of `constraintLayout`.

This code grabs all of the constraints present in the layout, make the desired change and reapplies the changes.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final ConstraintSet cs = new ConstraintSet();
    ConstraintLayout layout;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout);
    cs.clone(this, R.layout.activity_main);
    cs.constrainDefaultWidth(R.id.textViewChat, ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT_SPREAD);
    cs.applyTo(layout);
}
```